# odoo 8, JS extended method, issue with the context in the callback

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

I am extending a function in POS in odoo8, and I've come upon a problem, when i am calling backend via call (function 'ping') and in the callback self._super is null while self itself seems to be just fine. What could have caused the _super being changed to null? Thanky you for any assistance in the matter.

```
openerp.something = function(instance){    
var module   = instance.point_of_sale;

module.PaymentScreenWidget.include({
validate_order: function(options) {
    var self = this;
    var currentOrder = this.pos.get('selectedOrder').export_as_JSON();
    var companyVAT = this.pos.company.vat;
    var orderModel = new instance.web.Model('pos.order'); 

    orderModel.call('ping', [currentOrder, companyVAT]).then(function (responded) {
        if(responded)
            self._super(options);        
        else alert('didnt respond');
    });
    debugger;
}});};
```

Comment: hello apply before or after this._super(option)

Comment: user00000341 could you be more specific please. What to apply on what. Thanks, really appreciated

Comment: put the line  
self._super(option) after this line  var self = this;

Comment: That wont work well, since i need to call ping and receive it's result before i want to call the super. This is why i have "extended" validate order in the first place. Is it even possible?

Comment: if u add any method n overite any method then u can use extended but u want to use exiting method then u can use include

Comment: https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/how-can-i-extend-a-js-web-module-64

Comment: Thank you user but I want to use existing (i should probably say include instead of extend) method and i am using it. It all works perfectly until i go into asynchronous call (.call into python side) then i lose context. More specifically self._super becomes null, meaning i cannot call the original method anymore.

Comment: ok dear so i nee face problem !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: orderModel.call('ping', [currentOrder, companyVAT]).then(function (responded) {
        if(responded)
            self._super(options);      -->>> this row doesnt have _super anymore
        else alert('didnt respond');
    });      can you see the problem now